# Trying to use FFMPEG in C using Codeblocks IDE under Windows 8.1

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu, ffmpeg, codeblocks

I have been trying to use  FFMPEG in C using Codeblocks IDE under Windows 8.1.
 I've done the linking stuff required in order to make my code compile but i get the following error:

C:\Users\user\Desktop\MScProject\FFmpegTest2\main.c|82|error: 'CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO' undeclared (first use in this function)|

The source i use is the one from the following tutorial
http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.c

(original link: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html)

Any ideas ??
Thanks in advance !!
(btw the same thing happens when i am trying to compile the program in ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial is very good, but it is also very old. ffmpeg has renamed a lot of functions and macros. CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO is now AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO. you will find many more going through that tutorial. I usually have a copy of avformat.h avcodec.h and avutil.h open to reference while using the libav*